# Ubuntu server - Will it Run Oracle instant client?

Tags: lamp, oracle

We are looking to build a Scripting Server.
Will Ubuntu Server run the following Software?

need FTP access and ability to chmod folders

Also: 
PHP 5.5
cURL
MySQL
phpMyAdmin – preferably version 3.3.9 due to ability to export as .xlsx
mcrypt
oci8 with Oracle instant client 10.2.0.5.0 (newer versions cannot query certain databases)
PHPExcel
soap
Pear Mail

All the Lamp Software, I am good with, the Oracle Instant client, I am concerned about.
Any Suggestions on Platform?
Red Hat vs, Ubuntu server?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Oracle Instant Client by following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Oracle%20Instant%20Client). Of course you have to replace the 11.2 version numbers with the 10.2.0.5.0 version numbers.

I installed the Oracle Instant Client 10.2.0.5.0 in a VM running Ubuntu 14.04, and it works. Installing the php-oci8 module also works, but you have to use the oci8-2.0.11 version for PHP5 (see the output of `pecl remote-info oci8`):

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear php5-dev
sudo pecl install oci8-2.0.11
  # enter instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64/lib 
cd /etc/php5/mods-available
echo 'extension=oci8.so' | sudo tee oci8.ini
sudo php5enmod oci8
```

If you are using PHP7, this should work:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear php-dev
sudo pecl install oci8
  # enter instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.5/client64/lib 
cd /etc/php/7.0/mods-available
echo 'extension=oci8.so' | sudo tee oci8.ini
sudo phpenmod oci8
```

Comment: Thank You. I think Ubuntu Server should work pretty well than.

Comment: Thank you for the info, @JeffPuckettII. I edited the answer.